# does android tv lollipop support WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, sony, google-tv, android-tv

I want to write an app for android 5.0 Lollipop smart tv. I need to know if webRTC is supported by the native Chrome version which is installed in these devices.
Thanks.

Comment: why not test it out?

Comment: Because my Company wants a technical feseability study, now. Without programming.

Comment: Not sure you can test it out, it is not released yet... http://www.android.com/tv/

Comment: But definitely better place to ask at Google/Android forums. This is not about programming at all, you mention it as well "Without programming"...

Answer (score 0):

Android TV does not have a browser installed.

The 'TV app quality' page has a paragraph (TV-WB) that says: "For web content, the app uses WebView components and does not attempt to launch a web browser app."

developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tv.html

Comment: How did you get this info? Source?

Comment: The 'TV app quality' page has a paragraph (TV-WB) that says: "For web content, the app uses WebView components and does not attempt to launch a web browser app." https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tv.html

Comment: On the other hand, the WebView is basically an embedded browser.